Can't bootstrap sunbeam on ubuntu 22.04 - mongo service not running
I'm trying to bootstrap sunbeam for installing openstack on Ubuntu 22.04, but after some researches about juju, even I installed the newest version of mongodb, it still has error "mongo service not running". I'm using PC with CPU Intel Core i7-14700K, RAM 64GB. Here is the log:
Fetching Juju agent version 3.4.4 for amd64
Attempt 1 to download agent binaries from 'https://streams.canonical.com/juju/tools/agent/3.4.4/juju-3.4.4-linux-amd64.tgz'...\n
Agent binaries downloaded successfully.
5532039d5cc4981de6b12194f4824c4a31a02886727e2f73942c5937e351ac5b  /var/lib/juju/tools/3.4.4-ubuntu-amd64/tools.tar.gz
Installing Juju machine agent
2024-07-08 04:51:52 INFO juju.cmd supercommand.go:56 running jujud [3.4.4 5abe6dd51d9e7f8c997fb7bc0454454f430c48ea gc go1.20.14]
2024-07-08 04:51:52 DEBUG juju.cmd supercommand.go:57   args: []string{"/var/lib/juju/tools/3.4.4-ubuntu-amd64/jujud", "bootstrap-state", "--timeout", "20m0s", "--data-dir", "/var/lib/juju", "--debug", "/var/lib/juju/bootstrap-params"}
2024-07-08 04:51:52 DEBUG juju.agent agent.go:600 read agent config, format "2.0"
2024-07-08 04:51:53 INFO juju.agent identity.go:22 writing system identity file
2024-07-08 04:51:53 DEBUG juju.cmd.jujud bootstrap.go:444 starting mongo
2024-07-08 04:51:53 DEBUG juju.agent agent.go:978 potential mongo addresses: [localhost:37017]
2024-07-08 04:51:53 DEBUG juju.cmd.jujud bootstrap.go:473 calling EnsureMongoServerInstalled
2024-07-08 04:51:53 INFO juju.mongo mongo.go:240 Ensuring mongo server is running; data directory /var/snap/juju-db/common; port 37017
2024-07-08 04:51:53 INFO juju.packaging manager.go:102 installing "juju-db" via "snap"
2024-07-08 04:51:53 INFO juju.packaging.manager run.go:88 Running: snap install  --channel 4.4/stable juju-db
2024-07-08 04:51:53 DEBUG juju.mongo mongo.go:420 using mongod: /snap/bin/juju-db.mongod --version:
db version v4.4.24
Build Info: {
    "version": "4.4.24",
    "gitVersion": "0b86b9b7b42ad9970c5f818c527dd86c0634243a",
    "openSSLVersion": "OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020",
    "modules": [],
    "allocator": "tcmalloc",
    "environment": {
        "distarch": "x86_64",
        "target_arch": "x86_64"
    }
}

2024-07-08 04:52:03 DEBUG juju.mongo mongo.go:315 attempt 1 to start mongo service: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
2024-07-08 04:52:23 DEBUG juju.mongo mongo.go:315 attempt 2 to start mongo service: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
2024-07-08 04:52:53 DEBUG juju.mongo mongo.go:315 attempt 3 to start mongo service: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
2024-07-08 04:53:43 DEBUG juju.mongo mongo.go:315 attempt 4 to start mongo service: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
2024-07-08 04:54:53 DEBUG juju.mongo mongo.go:315 attempt 5 to start mongo service: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
2024-07-08 04:56:02 DEBUG juju.mongo mongo.go:315 attempt 6 to start mongo service: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
ERROR failed to start mongo: max duration exceeded: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
2024-07-08 04:56:02 DEBUG cmd supercommand.go:549 error stack: 
mongo service not running
github.com/juju/retry.Call:216: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
github.com/juju/retry.Call:206: max duration exceeded: attempt count exceeded: mongo service not running
github.com/juju/juju/cmd/jujud/agent.(*BootstrapCommand).Run:295: failed to start mongo
2024-07-08 04:56:02 DEBUG juju.cmd.jujud main.go:287 jujud complete, code 0, err <nil>
13:56:02 ERROR juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:989 failed to bootstrap model: subprocess encountered error code 1
13:56:02 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:990 (error details: [{github.com/juju/juju/cmd/juju/commands.(*bootstrapCommand).Run:1088: failed to bootstrap model} {github.com/juju/juju/environs/bootstrap.Bootstrap:738: } {github.com/juju/juju/environs/bootstrap.bootstrapIAAS:669: } {subprocess encountered error code 1}])
13:56:02 DEBUG juju.cmd.juju.commands bootstrap.go:1814 cleaning up after failed bootstrap
13:56:02 DEBUG juju.utils.ssh ssh.go:305 using OpenSSH ssh client
13:56:03 DEBUG juju.provider.manual environ.go:308 script stdout: 
jujud stopped

13:56:03 DEBUG juju.provider.manual environ.go:309 script stderr: 
+ stopped=0
+ pkill -SIGABRT jujud
+ wait_for_jujud
+ for i in {1..30}
+ pgrep jujud
+ echo jujud stopped
+ stopped=1
+ logger --id jujud stopped on attempt 1
+ break
+ [[ 1 -ne 1 ]]
+ [[ 1 -ne 1 ]]
+ service juju-db stop
Failed to stop juju-db.service: Unit juju-db.service not loaded.
+ exit 0

13:56:03 INFO  cmd supercommand.go:556 command finished

So does anyone have any ideas to fix that problem related to mongodb? Thanks!

I just started doing this.  The script has had a lot of speed bumps that I think are things you might have to navigate.  This seems like the next step is to install mongo manually and see if that helps.

Looks like that didnt work.  might have to figure out what sunbeam is next.

Looks like my problem is I am installing Ubuntu 24.04 and juju doesnt support it.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/juju/+bug/2065593
